# Why do people still leave flowers at the Temple of Julius Caesar?

Tags: ancient-rome, archaeology, caesar

I visited Rome recently and did an audio tour through the Colosseum and Roman Forum archeological sites. In the Roman Forum there is the remains of the Temple of Caesar, where Julius Caesar was cremated.

Here is a photo of the site from my visit:
[image: Flowers at Temple of Caesar]

As you can see, there are flowers that have been recently placed at the site, and apparently they are regularly placed there. My question is, why? He died so long ago that surely no one has any close connection to him, though I know he was deified, so perhaps there are some that still worship him?

Or is it perhaps just organised by the staff at the Roman Forum as a tourist attraction? All I've been able to find on the internet is that there is fresh flowers there all year around, which makes it seem strange someone would pay to enter every day to lay them there.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: people leave flowers at many monuments out of respect for the people commemorated there, irrespective of blood or even cultural ties.

Comment: The same reason could be why there are monuments on the Thermopilae battlefield.

Comment: More important than the fact that he died a long time ago, is the fact that he was a tyrant that destroyed the Roman republic forever and invoked a civil war that killed thousand of Romans. This is really weird that the descendants of the ancient Romans have any respect for him.

Comment: It's not uncommon to see flowers/offerings left at many historical monuments across Europe, but I think the keyword here is *still*. This is not something that has been continuing from some far-flung past, but very much a development of the 20th and 21st centuries, though the religious persuasion isn't represented in the offerings they appear very similar to modes of dedication made as a part of modern-spiritual and pagan movements common across Europe... Caesar was deified after all.

Comment: For what it is worth, people also (allegedly) still put potatoes on the [grave](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Friedrich_II_Tomb_P7140136.JPG) of [Frederick the Great](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/Der_K%C3%B6nig_%C3%BCberall2.JPG). This may just be one of the touristy things that people do, just like throwing coins into the Trevi fountain or scaling the Spanish stairs.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like it has a relation with the "souvenir" of the Italian kingdom and the fascist era :

> The Temple is gone, and the podium was long ago stripped of its marble casings and bronze rostra: various Popes found pious uses for all that. Part of the massive concrete core of the podium remains, and in front of it, behind a nondescript wall and under that inelegant semi-circular tin roof is a low mound, the remains of the Caesar's altar, that gets fresh floral decoration every day. On most days there are only a few blooms, but sometimes, on days that always seem to coincide with monarchist and (Divine Julius forbid!) Fascist remembrances, there are many more. A line of school children often waits to squeeze into the narrow space from which you can see the mound. *[mmdtkw.org](http://www.mmdtkw.org/VTempleCaesar.html)*